# Unable to import RClusteredMap in java program

Tags: java, maven, redis, redisson

I have added the below maven dependency into my project, even then I am not able to resolve RClusteredMap in my code.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
<artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
<version>3.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting RClusteredMap could not be resolved in below line-

RClusteredMap map = redisson.getClusteredMap("anyMap");

Am I missing anything, or RClusteredMap is supposed to be part of future releases of redisson (i tried many versions but same issue).

Comment: Please edit and add a clear question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RClusteredMap` object is a part of [Redisson PRO](https://redisson.pro) product and supported as part of `Data partitioning in cluster mode` feature.